# Best way to fetch emails from an email account and perform an async function with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, email, imap

What would be the best non-block way to fetch emails from my account (Im using GMAIL, can use any, the service doesn't matter) and depending on the subject/body it runs an AXIO/CHEERIO or Puppeteer scraper, so async would be the best.

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking for a 'way' to do it, I'll assume that you are asking how can you do it.

You can use the `Axios` package.

It's promised-base.

A basic example:

```js
axios.get('/')
.then(data=> //do something)
.catch(err => //handle it)
```

But you'll have to read into the gmail api for details if you really want to interact with gmail that way.

I can only answer till here as the question does not provide any more specific information.

Comment: how would you use axios to interact with a Gmail inbox?

Comment: I can only be as specific as the question gets.